# DateTimePicker in Gutenberg sidebar

Tags: wordpress, datetimepicker, sidebar, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm coding a plugin that adds a Gutenbeg sidebar to set some new properties for a post (using meta), it includes some dropdowns, text, checkbox, datetimepicker and so on; all is working as expected, storing and retrieving the correct data from post meta.
My problem is with DateTimePicker compononent, despite the fact it works correctly, it display in a ugly way, with the calendar extended and above it the date and time selection, with no ability to set a title/label to it. I was thinking about using the popover solution that is used in the main gutenberg sidebar for publishing, but i cant find any docs on how to open a popover clicking on a text, put the datepicker inside the popover, update the linked text on date selection
any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this:

```jsx
<Dropdown
    position="middle left"
    renderToggle={ ( ( { isOpen, onToggle } ) => (
        <Button isLink onClick={ onToggle } aria-expanded={ isOpen }>
            { currentDate ? date( 'd.m.Y H:i', currentDate ) : "placeholder" }
        </Button>
    ) ) }
    renderContent={ () => (
        <DateTimePicker
            currentDate={ currentDate }
            onChange={ newDate => /* update date */ }
        />
    ) }>
</Dropdown>
```

The `isLink` adds the `is-link` class to the button so that it looks like a link. Use the date package to format the date.

- [Dropdown component](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/dropdown/)
- [DateTimePicker component](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/date-time/)
- [date package](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-date/)